# Use page template for custom $_GET content

Tags: pages, page-template

I have a list of products, and I want to be able to click a link and get to a page with more information about the product, which I  can do using `$_GET` like so:

```
$s .= '<p><a href='.get_site_url().'/wp-content/plugins/real-wp-shop/test.php?info='.$value->id.'>Details</a></p>';
```

And then in `test.php` I have:

```
if (isset($_GET['info'])) {
    echo 'string';
}
```

With that, I obviously just get a blank page with `string` written on it, but I was wondering if it would be possible to use a page temnplate on this page, so I would get `string` written in the area of the page template (like where I would get the output If I had a post loop on a regular page) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter to load a template file from your theme:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_page_template', 99 );
function my_page_template( $template ) {

    if ( isset( $_GET['info'] ) &&  $_GET['info'] == 'some_value' ) {
         $new_template = locate_template( array('my-template.php' ) );
         if ( '' != $new_template ) {
             return $new_template ;
         }
     }
     return $template;
}
```

If you want to check the tempalte file within any other location you can. For example, you can check if the theme/child theme has the template file you want to load, if not, load a default template file from your plugin path:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_page_template', 99 );
function my_page_template( $template ) {

    if ( isset( $_GET['info'] ) &&  $_GET['info'] == 'some_value' ) {

        $new_template = locate_template( array('my-template.php' ) );

        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            //my-template.php file has been found in theme/child theme folder
            $template = $new_template ;
        } else {
            //load template callback when the file dosen't exist in theme
            $template = PATH_TO_MY_PLUGIN . '/my-template.php';
        }

    }

    return $template;

}
```

See also [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) filter.

Comment: This looks good, but I can't figure it out. Where would I put this? It can't go inside `test.php` as it is, since it won't recognize `add_filter` function.

Comment: `add_filter()` is a function from Wordpress that add filters to differents actions and events in Wordpress. Be familiar with filter and action hooks in Wordpress is a must if you want to extend or customize Wordpress functionality and output. You can see [`add_filter()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) and [`add_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) in the Codex.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can create a page template to use and in that use the following:

```
if (isset($_GET['info'])) {
  echo $_GET['info']
}
```

1. Copy your default page template and creating a new one based on that. Make sure you change the value of the 'Template Name: XXXXX' also. The template should use the get_header and get_footer commands above/below your new code as a mimimmum to apply the website template to the page.
2. Create a new page and apply the template to that page.

If you get stuck, let me know and I'll guide you more once I understand where you're having problems.

Comment: But how would I make it default to that page? Should I change something in my link? As you can see, right now it links to a php file inside my plugin folder. Should I change that?

Comment: I think you need to have a read of these pages for an understanding of templates: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates & http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_into_Templates

Once you have created the file, it should go in your theme folder, not the plugins folder.